# Escuchar atributo de una clase js en VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hola estoy creando un array de objetos  en Vue, y necesito escuchar un atributo que al cambiar llame a un método.

```
class miClase{

 constructor( atributo ) {
   this.atributo = atributo; 
 }
}



....

vue

... , 

data(){

 var_vue = null 

}, ...
```

Los datos al objeto vue los cargo en el mounted :

```
mounted(){

  this.var_vue =mi_clase_instanciada.atributo;

},...
```

y después intento observar esa variable en el watch:

```
watch(){
 var_vue: function( new , old ){ cosas que hacer... }, 
 deep: true // Para que compruebe todos los atributos y si alguno cambia .... 
....},...
```

Todo esto no me funciona !!

He intentado crear el watch dinamicamente en el mounted

```
mounted() {

    for (let index in this.var_vue) {
        this.$watch(['var_vue', index, 'atributo'].join('.'), (newVal, oldVal) => {
            .algo que hacer .... 
        });
    }

},
data() {
    return {
        var_vue: [mi_clase, mi_clase]
    }
}
```

extraído de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283891/vue-js-watch-array-of-objects

Tampoco me genera el evento cuando cambia mi atributo

La solución que he aplicado  es poner en mis clases la llamada al evento que necesito después de que se llame a uno de los eventos principales pero no me convence pq me dispara ese evento tantas veces como clases hay instanciadas + 1 .
Pero no es la solución optima

Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El problema no es nada de lo que vos pones, si no que los objetos no son reactivos a menos que los hayas seteado como dice el manual de vue

Comment: Gracias, voy a buscar lo que me comentas

Comment: Fijate si esta pregunta generica a la cual le estamos dando forma te ayuda con tu problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/231399/324

Comment: Por que tienes una clase? Las clases requieren mayor procesamiento (vue tiene mucha influencia de react y en react dejaron de usar clases por que es mejor el rendimiento en base a funciones) Tanto computed como watch observan los cambios en el estado o valores del componente, Te recomiendo trabajar sobre estas funciones Saludos espero sirva JJ