# Problemas generando formulario dinámico Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

Desde hace unos días he estado intentando generar un formulario dinámico a través de un JSON que viene desde una petición GET a través de Axios. El problema que tengo es que tan solo me carga el comienzo del fichero, mientras que si lo cargo directamente si me lo carga bien.

¿Alguien sabría decirme como puedo cargarlo de forma completa tras la llamada?

Json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Listado de campañas ",
  "properties":{
    "nombre": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 8,
      "maxLength": 80,
      "title": "Campaña",
      "attrs": {
        "placeholder": "Introduce el nombre de la campaña",
        "title": "Por favor introduce la campaña"
      }
    },
    "descripcion": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 8,
      "maxLength": 80,
      "title": "descripcion",
      "attrs": {
        "placeholder": "Introduce la descripción de la campaña",
        "title": "Por favor introduce la descripción de la campaña"
      }
    },
    "mes": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 8,
      "maxLength": 100,
      "title": "Mes",
      "enum": ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
      "attrs": {
        "placeholder": "Por favor introduce el mes de la campaña",
        "title": "Por favor introduce el mes de la campaña"
      }
    },
    "Sfid": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 8,
      "maxLength": 80,
      "title": "Sfid",
      "attrs": {
        "placeholder": "SFID",
        "title": "Por favor introduce el SFID"
      }
    },
    "Grupo": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 120,
      "title": "Grupo",
      "attrs": {
        "type": "email",
        "placeholder": "Tu Grupo",
        "title": ""
      }
    },
    "CHome": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Código Home",
      "enum": ["Codigo 1", "Codigo 2"],
      "attrs": {
        "placeholder": "Selecciona tu Código",
        "title": "Selecciona tu Código"
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["nombre", "Sfid", "CHome"]
}
```

Metodo de axios que lo llama:

```
getMenu: function () {
        instance.get("/servicioPrueba/Campa").then(response => {
        this.schema= response.data

        })
```

Fragmento de carga del fichero .vue que hace que si se cargue bien desde el comienzo(o sea haciendo carga directa de un fichero desde disco)

```
  export default {
    mounted: function () {
       this.getMenu()
    },

    data: () => ({ 
      schema: require('../schema/Campa'),
      //schema: {},         
      model: {}
    }),
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que tiene schema una vez que vuelve del axios? te fijaste?

Comment: Schema al retornar desde el axios contiene un objeto Observer que contiene varios pares de datos a modo k,v, que eso si carga, pero contiene un objeto dentro (properties) que es lo que no carga ni renderiza

Comment: Fijate si tu problema no es este: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231385/324. Y por favor, lee los links que te pase para saber como funciona el sitio.

Comment: Si que la solución iba por esa via, ahora edito mi post colocando la solución que acabé aplicando. Por otro lado ya revisé los links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré una solución parecida a esta cuestión es.stackoverflow.com/q/231385/324

El problema era el mismo, el componente de data si que cambia cogía el json traído desde el servicio web, pero no se recargaba el objeto en si, para ello busqué soluciones de recarga y la que mejor se adaptó a mi construcción fue la siguiente:

```
<template>
  <el-card class="form">
    <form-schema ref="formSchema" :schema="schema" v-model="model" :key="schema">
      <el-button type="primary" @click="submit">Alta</el-button>
      <el-button type="reset">Reset</el-button>
    </form-schema>
  </el-card>
</template>
```

Es añadir al componente del template que queremos recargar el parámetro :key y así decirle que cuando cambie lo que tiene asociado :key se recargue el componente

En este caso lo coloqué en el *form-schema*