# Re-renderizar en vue al actualizar el estado

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3

> Tengo una lista de informacion que viene de una API, y un paginador abajo. El paginador funciona correctamente, y yo puedo ver el objeto `resultados` en el `state` de `vuex` actualizarse correctamente. Sin embargo, en el `DOM` no se registra el cambio.
> (Si por ejemplo, voy a `vs code`, hago cualquier cambio minimo, le doy guardar al archivo, y automaticamente se renderizan los elementos que corresponden a la pagina.)
> Yo quisiera que esto se haga en tiempo real. Creo que deberia meterlo dentro de la funcion `onUpdated()`, ya que la consola se ejecuta correctamente cada vez que doy click en el paginador.

Este es mi componente:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="resultados !== undefined && resultados.count > 0">
    <p>Offset: {{ resultados.offset }}</p>
    <p>Limit: {{ resultados.limit }}</p>
    <p>Count: {{ resultados.count }}</p>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in resultados.propiedades" :key="index">
      <Card :item="item" :index="index" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Paginación</h5>

      <Paginator
        :first="Number(resultados.offset)"
        :rows="10"
        :totalRecords="resultados.count"
        :rowsPerPageOptions="[10, 20, 30]"
        @page="onPage($event)"
      ></Paginator>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>No hay resultados para su búsuqeda</div>
</template>

<script>
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import { computed, onUpdated, ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { useStore, mapActions } from "vuex";

import Paginator from "primevue/paginator";

export default {
  name: "ListaResultados",
  components: {
    Card,
    Paginator,
  },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    const reset = () => {
      first.value = 0;
    };

    onUpdated(()=>{
      console.log('updated')
    })

    const onPage = ($event) => {
      let url = 'http://api.miweb.com.ar/properties/search'
      store.dispatch('filtros/offsetAction',$event.first)
      store.dispatch('resultadosPropiedades/fetchResultadosAction',url)
    };

    return {
      onPage,
      reset,
      resultados: computed(
        () => store.state.resultadosPropiedades.resultado.data
      ),

      ...mapActions("filtros", ["limitAction", "offsetAction"]),
      ...mapActions("resultadosPropiedades", ["fetchResultadosAction"]),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Interesante.. tu problema vendra por [aca](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/change-detection.html#for-arrays)??? estaria bueno ver como cargas ese arrray...

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi ahora voy a leer ese articulo. ``resultados`` es un objeto, no un array. Cuando me encuentro en la primer pagina del paginador, el objeto ``resultados`` ya tiene datos. Los saco de la store, y fueron cargados previamente en un buscador. Lo que hace la función onPage es simplemente cambiar la propiedad ``offset`` en el ``state``de ``filtros`` (tengo la store modularizada). Luego se ejecuta la accion ``fetchResultadosAction`` que envia el state ``filtros`` como parametros, ejecuta una mutacion y me cambia los resultados por los que corresponden a la página... (sigue)

Comment: ... que yo selecciono. Puedo ver el cambio en tiempo real del objeto desde el devtools. El objeto ``resultados`` (que es el return de una propiedad computada) muta correctamente. Capaz deberia probar cambiar la computada por un getter?

Comment: hay tambien una forma de hacer reactivos los cambios en los objetos, mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231385/mi-objeto-no-reacciona-a-los-cambios)

Comment: @gbianchi ya encontre por donde venia el problema, si yo en lugar de llamar al componente Card ``<Card :item="item" :index="index" />`` llamo solamente a los ``{{item}}`` dentro del loop, todo funciona como corresponde. El problema no estaba en este codigo, sino en mi componente CARD, donde no estoy recibiendo correctamente el estado.

Comment: No sé si la pregunta en lugar de ayudar, terminará confundiendo. Así que en un rato creo que la voy a borrar. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo :D

Comment: habria que ver entonces porque no esta siendo reactivo Card... te faltaran unos watch de las props en card? eso no lo mostraste...

Comment: @gbianchi exacto, el error es mio, el componente card apenas existe, no le habia configurado nada en su interior. Estaba buscando el problema en el lugar equivocado :S

Comment: ok. la cerramos como no reproducible entonces